# Google Analytics 4 Data upload

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way to upload all of the data from GA3 to GA4? I've tried uploading CSV files downloaded from GA3 although I keep running into record errors.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying data structure of Universal analytics and analytics ga4 is completely different.

UA analytics was based upon pageviews and screen views.  While ga4 everything its based on events.

There is no way to covert UA data to GA4 because they are so different.

Beyond that Google analytics is hit based as in a point of time.  While you can insert offline data that data would be no more then a few hours old.  Inserting data from a website that had been recording data for years would not be possible.

[Universal Analytics will be going away](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11583528?hl=en)

> After July 1, 2023, you'll be able to access your previously processed data in your Universal Analytics property for at least six months. We know your data is important to you, and we strongly encourage you to export your historical reports during this time.

The only real option google is giving us is to export it to a csv.